# Fontforge/Illustrator problems with SVG files and fonts

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, font-design, font-forge

This is my first attempt at designing a font.

I created SVGs in Adobe Illustrator 2022 from editing an open-source font, typing, then converting the text to paths, then manipulating before saving as an SVGs. I then imported them into FontForge, which I am fairly new to, but some of the SVGs aren't displaying as intended.

I believe I have a mixture of problems with open paths, clockwise and anticlockwise etc. I am unsure if I need to fix these in Illustrator or in FontForge.

I am creating a broken text font for an art project so the letters are supposed to look like they do in the vector forms (but not how they do in the FontForge grid). I am not a graphic design professional, simple explanations would be appreciated.

I have put some screenshots from FontForge.

[image: Capital B vector but in grid appears blank]
[image: Capital O vector but in grid appears blank]
[image: lower case p vector but in grid appears as inverse]
[image: Capital Q vector but in grid appears blank]
[![Capital B code][5]][5]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 26.2.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1000 1000;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{display:none;}
    .st1{display:inline;fill:none;}
    .st2{display:inline;}
    .st3{font-family:'BitstreamVeraSansMono-Roman';}
    .st4{font-size:800px;}
    .st5{display:inline;fill:#878787;}
</style>
<g id="Layer_1" class="st0">
    <rect x="213.07" y="192" class="st1" width="573.85" height="684.77"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 259.1799 799.9963)" class="st2 st3 st4">B</text>
</g>
<g id="Layer_4">
    <g>
        <path d="M403.14,457.42V800h-79.3v-583.2h79.3V457.42"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="Layer_6" class="st0">
</g>
<g id="Layer_7" class="st0">
</g>
<g id="Layer_5" class="st0">
</g>
<g id="Layer_2" class="st0">
</g>
<g id="Layer_3" class="st0">
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. If you want to share code, please don't just post an image of it. Add it as text in your question, highlight it, and use the Code Sample button in the text editor.  You can also share SVGs over at SVGshare.com

Answer (score -1):

> ...but some of the SVGs aren't displaying as intended.

- You need to create that SVG which is having a problem afresh.  Do it from scratch.  Do not modify the existing one.

> I believe I have a mixture of problems with open paths, clockwise and
> anticlockwise etc. I am unsure if I need to fix these in Illustrator
> or in FontForge.

- These can be fixed in FontForge.  While generating fonts you get errors for these. You can select all and try to fix the clockwise/anticlockwise issues. A video on this - https://youtu.be/MoLrnPm33Ao

Comment: Hi Kishore and welcome to GD.SE! Please provide a summary of the relevant parts when you link to a video to avoid link rot. Thanks!